# How do i login to this site with scrapy shell and python - 401 Error?

Tags: python, post, scrapy

Im trying to login to this website, seeking.com/login through scrapy shell.  i also installed burp suite to analyze its url and headers, etc.

```
from scrapy.http import FormRequest
frmdata = {"captcha":"","email":"MYEMAIL.com","password":"MY_PASSWORD","is_rememberme":"0","locale":"en_US","auth_type":"bearer_token","date":"2018-12-13T09:56:22.957Z"}


url = "https://www.seeking.com/v3/auth/login"
r = FormRequest(url, formdata=frmdata)
fetch(r)
```

with this code i get a HTTP 401 Error, as far as i can tell essentially an authentication error.

I forwarded the calls through burpsuite and got the following intercept.

```
POST /v3/auth/login HTTP/1.1
Host: www.seeking.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:63.0) 
Gecko/20100101 Firefox/63.0
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: https://www.seeking.com/login?fromLogout=1
Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
Web-Version: 3.59
Authorization: Basic NTI2ZTIwYzExMDI0NDYzNTk5OTI5MzUwZThiNWEzMTI6bHN0emd4ZzpSRzRzS3VmdEJMRTQxMm92TnMxbDR6L0ZkZ1dESHZuM2wwZWxtYWhyMGtnPQ==
Content-Length: 166
Connection: close
Cookie: __cfduid=dcf9fd66583d55382f362c18a83d904ca1544519479; 
_gcl_au=1.1.2035701377.1544519485; _ga=GA1.2.1740241044.1544519486; 
com.silverpop.iMAWebCookie=e88c45d1-3c24-11c6-089e-e287aae2c678; 
__cfruid=3eebbdc1e401ed560c23a7c474c41e59b2e93018-1544520179; 
device_cookie=1; __gads=ID=a1e437c03ddad1b3:T=1544519579:S=ALNI_MYb30xY4z76J4NniCK_ZtOyOdPMKA;_lb_user=gfpuzje6kg; seeking_session=eyJpdiI6Im4yMTNJNVNRZjkxbnZzMmNpYnQ4dkE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiVGhGVUJDejc1dElJbEwxekh5d2hXUnhjeDlpVWR2dW9IWWJqeDZvRmI3VU9Pc1lpZXZGWGJxejQ1alNXbGVXUGJqaEpORU9LNFJITVh0N3IwR1E0bUE9PSIsIm1hYyI6IjUyODU3MWIxYjM3MGU3M2E0YjI1YzM2MzNmNDc5ZDMzZDdjYTg1ZWMxYWU2ODJjY2JlMTJmZWJlNmUyZDkyNWMifQ%3D%3D {"captcha":"","email":"MYEMAIL","password":"MYPASS","is_rememberme":0,"locale":"en_US","auth_type":"bearer_token","date":"2018-12-14T09:15:56.016Z"}
```

I am completely new to this, and have spent 2 days trying to figure out what i need to pass to this POST to login.

My question is

1) based on this intercept what should my request via FormRequest look like?

2) I see there are cookies/authorization (Authorization token, that changes with each POST, session cookies, etc) tokens that are being passed in to the post...  Where do they come from?  How do i get them when i am scraping so that i can successfully login?

3) Do i need to store these session variables when scraping other pages on the site after login? Anything special i need to do to stay logged in to access other pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the login page is expecting to be passed soon data, and not a url-encoded string (which is what `FormRequest` will create).

Something like this should work:

```
r = scrapy.Request(
    url=url,
    method='POST',
    body=json.dumps(frmdata),
    headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
)
```

The tokens, cookies, etc. are probably created when you initially request the login page, so you *might* need to request the login page before trying to log in.
It is possible that some of it is generated with javascript (haven't checked), so you might need to dig through the js code to figure out what's going on, or even execute the js yourself (e.g. using a browser).

Scrapy will keep track of your session for you, so there's nothing you need to do to stay logged in.

Comment: im getting this error. TypeError: Unsupported response type: Request

Comment: When doing what exactly?

Comment: `r` is the request, try `view(response)`

Comment: ahh, thanks! so, im now logged in and can just run through all the other urls on the site?

Comment: Right, unless something you do logs you off, in which case you would need to log in again.

Comment: direclty after i login, im  doing the exact same scrapy.Request() call but with a search url with paramaters and i get code 200 , but the page is empty, but when i do it in browser i see search results.  How can i tell if im still logged in?

Comment: actually, i viewed the response body and it looks like javascript.  any idea how to get the info out of javascript?

Comment: Either read it, figure out what it does, and reproduce that, or use something to execute the javascript for you (e.g. a browser).

Comment: i logged in and now i attempt to navigate to another page and i get a 500 Internal server error.... Its not javascript, i realized i was recieving json.  ideas?